# JAVA - Get maximum password age (maxPwdAge) from AD using JDNI or SpringLDAP?

Tags: java, spring, active-directory, ldap, jndi

Is there a way to retrieve the `maxPwdAge` value from the group policy?

I use `JNDI` and also SpringLDAP  to look up users and I can able to modify the user password , add new users etc... in the  `MS Active Directory` *(LDAP)*. This works fine .

but I also want to know the maximum password age for the user which is to be found in the policy. I have seen different articles about domainDNS but nothing really useful.

Also is there any way to retrieve the `maxPwdAge` in **spring LDAP** ?

Hope I will get a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an attribute of the relevant policy entry, if there is one. If it's in the directory and you have read access, you can retrieve it. If not, you can't.

Comment: I can modify the password in the AD . But I don't know the object for `Max Password age` ?